# Why theories about the cap three cases can not be together(Consistency,Availability,Partition tolerance)?

Tags: database, cap-theorem, nosql

CAP theorem suggests that the distributed systems can only provide you the two option of three options:**Consistency**, **Availability**, and **Partition** **tolerance** will have the remaining options will be offering other options.
In fact, why can not we have this 3 together? Please explain with an example.
[image]

Comment: Two interesting posts on the topic: [Please stop calling databases CP or AP](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html) and [Deconstructing the CAP theorem for CM and DevOps](http://markburgess.org/blog_cap.html)